# ajax search and scraping prices of bus page // maybe selenium?

Tags: python, java, ajax, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get prices of routes on a bus page
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

```
popup_linkz= list()
p=range(1, 2, 1)
for i in p:
                 
               
                    
                   
                
                def get_headers(session):
                    res = session.get("https://new.turbus.cl/turbuscl/inicio-compra")
                    if res.status_code == 200:
                        print("Got headers")
                        return res.text
                        
                    else:
                        print("Failed to get headers")
                        
                
                
                def search(session):
                    data = {
                            'origenInputModal': 'Santiago',
                            'destinoInputModal':'Calama',
                            'fechaRegreso': '03-04-2021',
                            'fechaIda': '31-03-2021',
                            
                        }
                    
                    res = session.post(
                        "https://new.turbus.cl/turbuscl/seleccion-itinerario", 
                        data=data) #not sure if this is the search link
                    if res.status_code == 200:
                        print("Search succeeded")
                        return res.text
                    else:
                        print("Search failed with error:", res.reason)
                    print(res.text)    
                 
                def get_popup_link(html):
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
                    
                    
                    for t in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'ticket_price-value'}):
                        precio = t.find('[class$="ticket_price-value"]').text
                        #cantidad = t.select_one('[id$="lblCantidad"]').text
                        #descripction = t.select_one('[id$="lblDescripcion"]').text
                        print(f"{precio=} {precio=}")
                    
                        #print()                
                        return precio
           
                def main():
                    with requests.Session() as s:
                        get_headers(s)
                        html = search(s)
                        popup_links = (get_popup_link(html))
                        print(popup_links)
                       # popup_linkz.extend(popup_links)
                        #print(popup_links)
                        #print(popup_linkz)
                        #download_html = get_download_html(s, popup_links)
                        # print(download_html)
                        #popup_linkz.extend(popup_links for i in range(0, 1, 1))
                main()
                
#a = popup_linkz
#print(a)

    enter code here
```

this is the link https://new.turbus.cl/turbuscl/inicio-compra

So right now I am able to find the input boxes of the search, but not sure were to run it.

I am getting this error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

so i am not so sure of what i am failing.

would you try to enlight me in order to succeed?

I have been trying all die and get a new approach with selenium in order to get search....

is right what i am doing or was better my first approach?

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Tue Mar 29 21:04:05 2022

@author: christian marcos
"""

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar 29 16:20:40 2022

@author: christian marcos
"""

from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pandas.io.html import read_html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



#select and fill firs field origin
driver=wd.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://new.turbus.cl/turbuscl/inicio-compra')

driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="origen"]').click();
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

#select and fill firs field 

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modalOriginCity"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]').click();
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post data needed is different. In this case, you need:

```json
{
  "fechaSalidaTramo": "31/03/2022",
  "mnemotecnicoCiudadOrigenTramo": "stgo",
  "mnemotecnicoCiudadDestinoTramo": "aric",
  "horaSalidaTramo": 0,
  "horaSalidaTramoMaxima": 0,
  "codigoLinea": 90,
  "numeroViaje": 0,
  "numeroCuentaCorrienteCliente": 0,
  "codigoIdaRegreso": 1,
  "cantidadAsientos": 1,
  "numeroRegistros": 0
}
```

And the link is, `https://new.turbus.cl/turbuscl/recursos/vtwst76/web1`.

In python, it'll look like this:

```py
import requests

HOST = "https://nclt.gov.in/"

LINK = "https://new.turbus.cl/turbuscl/recursos/vtwst76/web1"

DATA = '{"fechaSalidaTramo":"31/03/2022","mnemotecnicoCiudadOrigenTramo":"stgo","mnemotecnicoCiudadDestinoTramo":"aric","horaSalidaTramo":0,"horaSalidaTramoMaxima":0,"codigoLinea":90,"numeroViaje":0,"numeroCuentaCorrienteCliente":0,"codigoIdaRegreso":1,"cantidadAsientos":1,"numeroRegistros":0}'


HEADERS = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

def get_route(origin, destination):
    res = requests.post(LINK, data=DATA, headers=HEADERS)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        print("getting routes")
        return res.json()
    else:
        print(res)


def main():
    info = get_route("here", "there")
    print(info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**How I got to the answer**:

1. Go to the site.
2. Open the network tab, so I can see requests.
3. Do a search, and find the request that matches.
4. Copy the request as a curl request and import it into postman.
5. Remove headers, and see if you get an error when you do a request. Repeat until you have only the needed headers.
6. Copy the needed headers and data, and test it using requests.

Comment: Wow, totally work like a charm again, but I will like to focus on getting some info so I can Figure myself out how to, how did you get the host, link and data structure? , there has to be some trick about that doesnt? you can send my to study or what you want, but can you enlight me on what direction study in order to get that?

Comment: @ChristianFranciscoMarcosTor I added the steps at the end of my answer.

Comment: Invizi do you take sometimes projects for money , i will be really glad to pay you for some projects in future

Comment: @ChristianFranciscoMarcosTor You can message me directly at `<Code/>#0493` on discord.

Comment: just added you! thanks Invizi